# PHP if else statements does not work correctly

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I made a php comment-system but it seems that the codes are all right & I also I don't get any error message.

Here's my code:

```
 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce"); 
$errors = array();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = (isset($_POST['name']));
    $email = (isset($_POST['email']));
    $comment = (isset($_POST['comment']));

    if (empty($name)){
        $err['name1'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:30px;float:right;'>Please write down your name!</p>";
    }else{
        $name_length = strlen($name);
        if ($name_length > 2 ){
            if (!empty($email)){
                    $email_verification = test_input($email);
                    if (!filter_var($email_verification, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    $err['email1'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:25px;float:right;'>Your email is not written correctly!</p>"; 
                }else{
                    if (empty($comment)){
                        $err['comment1'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:25px;float:right;'>Please write your comment!</p>"; 
                    }else{
                        $comment_length = strlen($comment);
                        if (($comment_length < 5) || ($comment_length > 100)){
                            $err['comment2'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:25px;float:right;'>Your comment must be between 5 to 100 characters!</p>"; 
                        }else{
                            $que = $con->query("SELECT * FROM product_comments WHERE productcode='%s'", $_SESSION['pro_id']); 
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($que) == 0){
                            $insert_id2 = "insert into product_comments (productcode) values ('$product_id')";
                            $insert_id2 = mysqli_query($con, $insert_id2);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $err['email2'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:25px;float:right;'>Please write your email down!</p>"; 
            }
        }else{
            $err['name2'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:30px;float:right;'>Your name must be more than 2 words!</p>";
        }
    }

    //check errors
        if(count($err) == 0)
        {

            $insert_comment = "insert into product_comments (email,name,comment,modified_date, modified_time) values ('$email_verification','$name','$comment',CURDATE(), CURTIME())";
            $insert_comment = mysqli_query($con, $insert_comment);
            $succ = "<script>alert('Your comment is submitted correctly')</script>";
        }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <span>
        <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Your Name'/>
        <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email Address'/>
    </span>
        <textarea name='' name='comment' placeholder='Comment'></textarea>

        <input name='submit' style='font-family: BJadidBold, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' type='submit' value='Submit' class='btn btn-default pull-right'></input>
</form>
<p><?php if(isset($err['name1'])) echo $err['name1']; ?></p>
<p><?php if(isset($err['name2'])) echo $err['name2']; ?></p>
<p><?php if(isset($err['email1'])) echo $err['email1']; ?></p>
<p><?php if(isset($err['email2'])) echo $err['email2']; ?></p>
<p><?php if(isset($err['comment1'])) echo $err['comment1']; ?></p>
<p><?php if(isset($err['comment2'])) echo $err['comment2']; ?></p>
```

Everytime I want to submit the form with correct information I just get this **$err['name2']** error message which is

> Your name must be more than 2 words

I dont know why this happens so if you know what's wrong with it please let me know ... thanks!

Comment: `(isset($_POST['var']))` that isn't how it's used. You're probably attempting to use ternary syntax. Also make sure you started the session.

Comment: *"I also I don't get any error message"* - Probably because you're not looking for them. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: change `$name = (isset($_POST['name']));
    $email = (isset($_POST['email']));
    $comment = (isset($_POST['comment']));` to `$name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];`

Comment: Or use ternary operator there. use error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1) at top and also mysqli_error($connection object)

Comment: That `test_input()` function of yours, isn't enough to prevent SQL injection. Use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think:

```
$name = (isset($_POST['name']));
```

`isset()` returns a boolean.  It doesn't return the value of the thing it's checking.  Which means that `$name` isn't going to contain what you expect, which is resulting in this evaluating to `false`:

```
if ($name_length > 2 ){
```

(My *guess* is that `$name` ends up containing a 0 or a 1 when interpreted as a string, and thus `strlen($name)` resolves to `1`.)

Remove the `isset()` when trying to set the value:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: *"Remove the `isset()` when trying to set the value:"* - Or, use a ternary operator ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: True, but perhaps unnecessary in this case.  The code is already checking for the `submit` form value, and much of the remaining logic is input validation on the user-entered values.

Comment: No argument there David. I see he's already checking for `empty()`'ness. However, a ternary would cut down their code a lot.

Comment: `true` is string `"1"` and `false` is empty string `""`.

Comment: Well, I removed the isset() in line 5,6,7 but I get the error message-> Notice: Undefined index: comment

Comment: @EmLyrcisFarsi: Then there's no `comment` value being posted in your form.  Note that you're trying to define the `name` of a `textarea` twice, which may be resulting in undefined behavior: `<textarea name='' name='comment' placeholder='Comment'></textarea>`

Comment: @EmLyrcisFarsi as David wrote `name='' name='comment'` remove the first one `name=''`. Where you posted the same question http://stackoverflow.com/q/33790011/